# Display all posts in a page code for template

Tags: loop, page-template

I have found some code to display all posts in a page but it's not exactly what I need.

What I need to do is for example:

```
<h1>This is the Title</h1>

<p>This is the content of the posts. It displays part of the content only.
User need to click the More! link below to view the whole post.</p>

<a href="...">More!</a>
```

This code I found only displays the date and the title as a link.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
<li><?php the_time('d/m/y') ?>: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the code you listed only includes a reference for the title and the link.  Here's your original code, annotated ...

## Original

```
<?php $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed ?>

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Display the title of the current page that's listing your posts -->
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<!-- Create an unordered list to display a list of posts -->
<ul>

    <!-- Get a list of all posts, not including the first post -->
    <?php $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');

    // Loop through each post that your just grabbed
    foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>

        <!-- Add a list element for the post -->
        <li><?php the_time('d/m/y') ?>: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This will create a block that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>5/2/2012: <a href="">Post title</a></li>
    <li>5/2/2012: <a href="">Post title</a></li>
</ul>
```

## What You Should Do Instead

You just need to update your post template.  Right now, it's grabbing the posts and outputting the date published, a link, and the title.  So replace everything inside the `<ul> ... </ul>` with this:

```
<div class="post-list">
    <?php $myposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&offset=$debut' );
    foreach( $myposts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <!-- Only display part of the post so the user has to click "More!" -->
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More!</a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this ... just got 1 problem ... the the_excerpt doesn't show at all....Any ideas why?

Comment: I've added a call to `setup_postdata()` in case the post's content and excerpt aren't being set up right.  But anything beyond this, and you'll need some serious hands-on debugging of your site.  I recommend you open a thread in the [support forums](http://wordpress.org/supprt) for ongoing support ... this site isn't a support forum.